# htaccess redirect all request to index but not webroot directory

Tags: .htaccess

i have this htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

#set your rewrite base
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Deliver the folder or file if it exists on the server directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Push every request to index.php
#RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|pdf|css|map|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule !\.()$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(webroot)($|/) - [L]
```

it works but all files with the endings js,ico, ... have direct access.
now i need a htaccess that all request redirect to / 
and i think this rule is important

> RewriteRule !.()$ index.php [QSA,L]

but with one exception, all request they use the /webroot directory should not redirect (this is the folder with the images, css, js and so on)

I have no idea how to do this. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(webroot)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule !\.()$ index.php [QSA,L]
```